# Why HBASE write to WAL?

Tags: mysql, hbase, consistency

Can HBase with WAL enabled give better performance than MySQL? Since it has to anyhow write to DISK, which is same as MySQL writing records to disk? Does it make sense to use HBase in case I have a need to use consistent database?

I understand if my data is schemaless then I can go for HBase which can store consistent unstructured data. Now in case I have data in structured form with no relations, basically some data that can fit into MySQL and HBase, does it make sense to use HBase as I see if consistency is required it anyhow has a bottleneck of disk write every time  and same speed I feel can be provided by MySQL also.

Comment: Both MySQL and HBase might be faster, but for different queries. You're concerned about write speed, but what about reads? And there are all sorts of different writes. Single-row inserts, bulk data loads, updates, deletes, copying data from a query result into to table, and so on. To choose the most optimal database technology, you have to have a specific application with specific queries in mind, and then test both databases.

Comment: i want to use them to store data for my chat application between 2 users.Since i will be getting lot of chats, i want to use HBASE as it can store recent writes in memory but i also want strong consistency of my data.If i disable WAL then there can be some probability of me loosing data.This is my use case

Comment: I'm not talking about the use case, I'm talking about the code. You can't know which has better performance unless you test your code on both platforms.

Comment: okay, i thought someone might have done some analysis in past.I will try myself

Comment: I'm sure someone in the past has tested _their_ code on those two platforms, but there's no way they could have tested _your_ code.